# Gauss law and electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

[image]

In the above image there are two charges kept away from a point P, electric field at point P is non-zero according to couloumbs law but is zero if we consider a gaussian sphere  enclosing the charges.

Why is this so can anyone pls explain I simple terms.

Comment: Be careful about Gauss law: It cares about flux, not the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field from coulombs law
$$|\mathbf{E}|=k\left(\frac{q}{a^2}-\frac{q}{(r+a)^2}\right)$$
The flux through the given  gaussian surface from the gauss law
$$\oint_\mathcal{S}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=0$$
Note that you can't take out $\mathbf{E}$ from the integral so you can't conclude $\mathbf{E}=0$.

Comment: Ah sorry, that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

When we use a Gauss's Law to find the field from a point source (or other spherically symmetric charge distribution), we use a sphere as the Gaussian surface because we can see from symmetry that the field component normal to the surface must be equal at all points on the sphere.

In this problem you have two point sources, and no spherical symmetry. You can't assume (or prove, because it isn't true) that the normal component of the field is equal at all points on the sphere, and so you can't (because it's not true) prove that the field is zero at all points on the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field is not zero at point P according to Gauss's Law. The electric flux, through the entirety of the surface $ 4\pi R^2 $ (assuming it to be a sphere of radius R enclosing the point charges) is zero.

Mathematically, Gauss's Law states that, $$ \int \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = \frac{Q_{enclosed}}{ \varepsilon_{o}} $$

It doesnt imply in any way whatsoever that $ \vec{E}= 0 $, if the charge enclosed is zero.

The electric field varies over all the points on the Gaussian surface depending on the point's distance from the point charges. We take the dot of all these unique $ \vec{E} $ with a very small area element vector - $ \vec{dS} $ associated with that point and then combine all of those, with the help of integration. That quantity is directly proportional to the sum of the charges enclosed in the Guassian surface.